# There weren't any (instead of "get/recieve any")

Tags: word-usage

> **There weren't any** email attachments with the email you sent. Can you possibly resend it?
>
> I didn't **get/recieve any** email attachments with the email you sent. Can you possibly resend it?

Do both of them work and are both of them equally likely?

Thank you:)

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35845

Comment: "There weren't any", "I didn't get any" and "I didn't receive any" are all interchangeable and fine to use.